# How to maintain image aspect ratio in android in scrollview inside relative layout?

Tags: android, image, aspect-ratio

I have created a RelativeLayout with scrollable image between banner (height 48dp) and footer (48dp). While loading the image of size 767 X 1105 on a phone layout with resolution 320 x 480, the image width fits the device width but the height of the image is stretched which disturbs an aspect ratio. Kindly suggest the solution.

Below is the layout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/p_1_prastavana_1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/banner1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/topheadings" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/footer" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer1"
        android:layout_below="@id/banner1" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageSwitcher
                android:id="@+id/content_image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/p_1_prastavana_1" >
            </ImageSwitcher>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the problem, but ScrollViews should generally be set to "wrap_content" in the direction of their orientation.  There's also no need to put it in a LinearLayout.

Comment: you are downloading image from server or from sdcard